# Правильное испоьлзоване jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, объекты

Есть 3 объекта $('.ground') и 3 объекта $('.tip')
Надо, чтобы при наведении на $('.ground') i-тый высплывал $('.tip') i-тый

Через jQuery Object не получается
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

```
    <div class='ground'>red</div>
    <div class='ground'>green</div>
    <div class='ground'>blue</div>
    <div class='tip' style="background-color:red;"></div>  
    <div class='tip' style="background-color:green;"></div> 
    <div class='tip' style="background-color:blue;"></div>

   <script> 
    var gruond = $('.ground');

     for (i=0; i<=gruond.length; i++) {
            gruond[i].mouseenter(function(){ 
                $('.tip')[i].fadeIn("slow");
            })      

            gruond[i].mouseleave(function(){ 
                $('.tip')[i].fadeOut("slow");
            })
    }

</script>
```

Что тут не так?
http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/tcf43p96/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vz4p5uy9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
var gruond = $('.ground');

  $('.ground').mouseenter(function(){ 
     var i = $(this).index('.ground');
      $('.tip:eq('+ i +')').fadeIn("slow");
  })  

  $('.ground').mouseleave(function(){ 
      var i = $(this).index('.ground');
      $('.tip:eq('+ i +')').fadeOut("slow");
  })
 })
```

```css
.ground{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

.tip{    
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ground'>red</div>
<div class='ground'>green</div>
<div class='ground'>blue</div>
<div class='tip' style="background-color:red;"></div>  
<div class='tip' style="background-color:green;"></div> 
<div class='tip' style="background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендовал бы обратить внимание все таки на возможности css3 в частности вы можете более прозрачнее описать данную задачу всего лишь используя  `:hover` и `transition`
В любом случае почитайте вот тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions  это интересно. Да и стоит ли использовать jquery если браузеры нативно поддерживают множество интересных штуковин.

Хочу показаться грубым, но то как хотите вы решить задачу, похоже на костыли.

Answer (score 1):

gruond[i] в цикле не является объектом jQuery.
Можно его преобразовать в jQuery объект подобным образом -  $(ground[i]).
Также и $('.tip')[i] не является jQuery объектом, вариант $($('.tip')[i])

Полный код:

```
var gruond = $('.ground');
var tip = $('.tip');

for (let i=0; i<=gruond.length; i++) {
    $(gruond[i]).mouseenter(function(){ 
        $(tip[i]).fadeIn("slow"); // или $($('.tip')[i]).fadeIn("slow");
    })

    $(gruond[i]).mouseleave(function(){ 
        $(tip[i]).fadeOut("slow");
    })
}
```